# Background image doesn't display unless declared in master page

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

Using the style below (css file is linked to Default.aspx, which is then plugged into its master page), i want to control the color, repetition and image. The first two work fine but the image doesn't display.

```
body{
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: url('images/bg_01.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

When i add a style explicitly to the body tag on the master page, it works but boy it sure looks ugly. Why does it happen? How can i kill it?

```
<body style="background-image: url('images/bg_01.jpg');">
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: Are the image file names supposed to be different?

Comment: I've been testing different stuff to resolve the issue. Let's say they are the same. I'll edit the question.

Comment: image path in CSS must be relative to CSS file path

Comment: Are you sure the image is where you say it is? Remember, the path in the `url()` within a CSS file is **relative to the CSS file** - and not relative to the path of the page being displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `background-image: url()` in a CSS file, make sure that the image path in the CSS is **relative to the path of the CSS file**, and not relative to the page the CSS is being used in.

For instance, if your CSS file is located in `/styles/mystyle.css` and your image is located in `/images/image.jpg` then your url should be...

```
background-image: url(../images/image.jpg);
```

Comment: Oh, my god. I'm so {insert favorite profanity} stupid today... Please shoot me. At least twice.

Comment: And waste a bullet?! ;-)  Don't worry @Konrad, we all have days like that... good luck with your project